# Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Exceptions\SupportedLocalesNotDefined error given after install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-localization

I just install  'mcamara/laravel-localization' after install follow to steps and  add

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
], function(){ //...
});
```

to my route. After that, I encounter

```
Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Exceptions\SupportedLocalesNotDefined
Supported locales must be defined.
```

I guess it is not read to the config file for Supported locales array. So don't know how to fix it. I am using laravel 7.19.1. I need help.

Answer (score 2):

look.. if you have this line in Web.php file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath']], function ()
```

1- make it's as comment and run in terminal :
php artisan config:clear.
php artisan config:cache.

2- then delete comment from line.

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan config:cache
```

is fixed all.